# $y-x^2 \ge 0$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to which order?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples, convex-geometry

I am reading topology for the first time .I am stuck in a portion in Munkres which talks about order topology(section - $14$). Whatever I could understand from it is that when we define a convex set it is necessary to define an order.

Definition of convex set :$Y$ is called a convex set if $Y$ subset of $X$ ($X$ is an ordered set) then if $a < b$ of $Y$ holds then the entire interval $(a,b)$ of points of $X$ lies in $Y$.

Take the graph $y - x^2 \ge 0$ this is a convex set with respect to the definition that I know -Pick any two points in the set and join them using a line we see that the line is present inside the graph.

I am really confused that this happens with respect to which order ?This set is not convex with respect to dictionary order. Then what order did we use when we defined the set to be convex?

Comment: What is your definition of "an order" with respect to convexity?

Comment: I am talking of simple order in $X$ .

Comment: I think Munkres is just making a parenthetical remark about a linear continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in the context of subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ (or any real vector space), we have the following definition:

> A subset $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ is said to be convex, if for all $x, y \in S$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, it is the case that $tx + (1 - t)y \in S$.

In other words, given two points in $S$, the line segment joining the two points is contained in $S$.

This is different from convexity as defined in Munkres, which is defined for totally ordered sets (or "simply ordered sets").

Comment: So the definitions are not linked ?

Comment: @Antimony: Not as per my knowledge. The reason I could see Munkres using "convex" for simply ordered sets is that it sort of mimics the line segment definition. Namely, if you imagine a simply ordered set as a line (increasing elements listed from left to right), then convexity coincides (intuitively) with the definition above.

Comment: A set which is convex is not an interval or ray ?What is the closest example that comes to your mind?

Comment: What Munkres defines as a convex set is sometimes referred to as an interval. However, with Munkres' terminology, you can have convex subsets which are not an interval or ray. Indeed, consider the simply ordered set $\Bbb Q$ and its subset $S = \{x \in \Bbb Q : x^2 < 2\} \subset \Bbb Q$. Then, $S$ is a convex subset of $\Bbb Q$ but cannot be written as $(a, b)$ or $(a, b]$ or $[a, b)$ or $[a, b]$ for any $a, b \in \Bbb Q$. Thus, it is not an interval. It is easy to see that it is not a ray either.

Comment: The example that comes to my mind is like this:Consider $\{1,2\} \times Z_+$ under the dictionary order.Denoting $1 \times n$ as $a_n$ and  $2 \times n$ as $b_n$.We see that $Y= \{b_1,\cdots ,b_n ..\}$ is a convex set but I don't think it is an interval.However,is it a ray?

Comment: Also another example that I thought of is $X=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ and $Y=\{x  \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}: x > 0 \} $.Then Y is convex in X.However I dont think it is an interval or ray.What do you think @Aryaman

Comment: I also think another example will be $X=\mathbb{R}-{0}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^+$, then $Y$ is convex in $X$ but cannot be written as an interval or ray.

Comment: @Antimony Your first example is indeed not an interval and is in fact a ray. Your second example works too. Shankadeep above has also given a nice example.